# iOS MagicalRecord: Join

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

I want to get all records from table B where B.ID = A.ID (JOIN A/B). So, I created a method that is passing the object A, using predicate:

```
-(NSArray*) getRecordFromB:(A*) a{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];    
    NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a == %@", a];

    //Return notes from pin
    return [B MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate1 inContext:localContext];
}
```

And, it works perfectly. But, I think is better (I want to preserve memory) so I pass just the ObjectID to the method to make the join. I changed the method for:

```
-(NSArray*) getRecordFromB:(NSO*) a{
    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];    
    NSPredicate *predicate1 = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a.objectID == %@", a];

    //Return notes from pin
    return [B MR_findAllWithPredicate:predicate1 inContext:localContext];
}
```

But didn't work, because I don't have this attribute on my model A. Is there any better way to join two tables? Or I use my first method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass an object id instead of a managed object in the fetch request:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a == %@", a.objectID];
```

does exactly the same as

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"a == %@", a];
```

And if you already have the "A" object, it makes no difference at all if
you pass `a` or `a.objectID` to the fetch request.